# Recommended approach to externalize "secret" configuration in app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, configuration

I am planning to use a [JWT implementation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyJWT) on app engine (python, if it makes a difference) which will require me to have a secret string to have data signed.  At some point I would like to have the source (configuration files included) available in a public repository.  What is the best approach to externalize that secret string, without making the value public too?

There are 3 options I can think of, but none seem great:

1. Set environment variable in GAE console. (doesn't exist)
2. Keep separate repo of private things and mix in with script at deploy-time. (seems clunky)
3. Create my own "environment var" entity and keep data in datastore. (don't see console screen to manually put data into datastore)

Right now option #3 seems the most reasonable.  Is there a better or recommended approach to what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really want to separate the secret from the data.  If you are signing the data, I would really recommend #1 (or a hybrid of that really).  You can define an environment_variables section in your app.yaml:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables

```
env_variables:
   APPLICATION_SECRET: 'secret_goes_here'
```

You'll then want to prohibit code downloads for the application as an extra step to protect your secret:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Downloading_source_code.

Finally, you could use a method similar to the client_secrets.json that was done for the Google APIs client library if you really don't want to use environment variables:  https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets

Comment: Thanks, this is just the sort of advise I was looking for. I didn't realize that env section existed in the yaml either.

Comment: No problem, just make sure to limit access to source code and prohibit code downloads in GAE.